# How to return a value from a Function-style command in nightwatch.js

Tags: javascript, nightwatch.js

I am trying to create a custom command: getRandomValue in nightwatch.js, where I pass an array and get a random element as output. Is it possible? If yes how do I write the function and read the returned value in nightwatch test file. Trying to work on  something like this:

**getRandomValue.js**

```
exports.command = function(array) {
    this.getRandomValue(array,function callback(res) {
       value = this.array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)]
   })
   return value;
};
```

mytest.js

```
.getRandomValue(nums, function (result) {
          nums = result.value
          //console.log(nums)
        })
```